# forecasting weekly data using tbats

Tags: r, plot, time-series, data-mining, forecasting

so this is my data   [data](https://1fichier.com/?wanu1lltk5)
the data starts from 26/07/2016 and ends the 10/03/2017 
So 2 questions :
is this correct ? using tbats ? for a weekly seasonality ?
i want also the predicted data to look like the initial data but as shown that's not my case how can i do that ?
this is what i've got and here's the code too

[image]

i executed this commands to get finally this using tbts forecasting

```
      data.raw=read.csv(file=file.choose(),header=TRUE,sep=";",row.names=NULL)%>%
      mutate(date.re = as.POSIXct(date, format = "%d/%m/%Y"))
      complete.dates <- range(data.raw$date.re)
      dates.seq <- seq(complete.dates[1], complete.dates[2], by = "week")
      series <- data.frame(sale.week = week(dates.seq),sale.month =    month(dates.seq), sale.year = year(dates.seq))

      data.post <- data.raw %>%
      mutate(sale.week = week(date.re),sale.month = month(date.re),  sale.year = year(date.re)) %>%
      select(Quantite, sale.week,sale.month, sale.year) %>%
      group_by(sale.week,sale.month, sale.year) %>%
       summarize_all(funs(sum(.))) %>%
      right_join(series) %>%
      replace_na(list(Quantite = 0))

      data2=data.post[,4]
      sensor <- ts(data2,frequency=52)
      fit <- tbats(sensor)
      fc <- forecast(fit)
      plot(fc)
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are fitting correctly and forecasting correctly. However, you are specifying the seasonality incorrectly.

To get this into weekly seasonality you would most likely want to use

```
sensor <- ts(data2,frequency=7)
```

To understand this more you could read up on it [here.](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/seasonal-periods/) But basically it boils down to how many observations do you have before it falls again on the same day. So if you have 7 days of data in each weeks worth of data your frequency should be 7. If you only have 5 days of data for each week your frequency should be 5.

One of the benefits of tbats is that you can have two seasonal periods. You could specify both weekly and yearly seasonality by trying this:

```
library(forecast)
sensor <- msts(data2, seasonal.periods=c(7,365.25))
```

Another option would be to use ARIMA. You can only use one seasonal period with ARIMA though. You would want to use weekly. Using ARIMA will also allow you to include indicators such as holidays where you would expect to see unusually large or small sales. You could also use indicators for days before holidays if you expect them to be different than the normal trend as well.

I have done some weekly seasonality and have had the best luck using ARIMA mainly because you can include other covariates.

Other things you might want to consider are checking for outliers. You can do this with `tsoutliers()` which is also in the `forecast` package. And, sometimes you can get better results by transforming your data. So look into that too.

For more details you might want to read a little bit on time series. [This is an excellent book with many examples in R.](https://www.otexts.org/fpp)